# Why $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} \kappa(y)=0$ in certain situation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 14.109 and stuck at some point :

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true? By 'the correspondence of $x$ to a minimal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\otimes \kappa(y)$', I think that it means the Theorem 3.3 in next linked pdf : [http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/216APage/handouts/irreddim.pdf](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/216APage/handouts/irreddim.pdf)

And note that $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x} \cong R:= \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} \kappa(y)$ (c.f. [Showing that $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} \kappa(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503537/showing-that-mathcalo-f-1y-x-cong-mathcalo-x-x-otimes-mathca)) So, my question is, $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}  =0$?

In our case, the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}$ satisfies that its maximal ideal is minimal prime? Then may be $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}  =0$.

What will be good to notice?

Can anyone help?

EDIT : Below SiSi answered but I think that it is not complete : 1) the statement "The fibres of $f$ are equidimensional because $f$ is dominant and of finite type" can be false? c.f. : [For a morphism $f: X\to Y$ dominant, locally of finite type ($Y$ is some scheme), each fiber is equidimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552498/for-a-morphism-f-x-to-y-dominant-locally-of-finite-type-y-is-some-scheme)
2) And the reductibility to the case that "$f:\operatorname{Spec}(A)→\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ is dominant where $B$ is a discrete valuation ring with residue field $κ$ and field of fraction $K$ and $A⊂B$ is a finite type algebra over $B$." , is somewhat ambiguous : c.f. :  [For $y \in Y$, does there exists an open neighborhood $\operatorname{Spec}B$ where $B$ is DVR and containing the $y$ as the special point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549480/for-y-in-y-does-there-exists-an-open-neighborhood-operatornamespecb-whe/4549871#4549871). I don't know how we can reduce to that case.

Can anyone provide a more exact proof? Anyway I will struggling with the underlined statement.

**Furthur progress** : I found an associated proof : $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}  =0$ is true ; c.f. Lemma 3.2 of [http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/216APage/handouts/irreddim.pdf](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/216APage/handouts/irreddim.pdf)

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the underlined statement.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: is it clear to you once you know that $f$ is pure dimensional, i.e. the irreducible components of a fibre have the same dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. We can prove that $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}  =0$. In the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book, p.128, he wrote that "for an arbitrary scheme $X$ and a closed irreducible subset $Z$ with generic point $\eta$ we have

$$ \operatorname{codim}_X Z = \operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}= \inf_{z\in Z}\dim\mathcal{O}_{X,z}. $$

If needed, I will upload its proof in detail.

In our situation of the question, $x$ is the generic point of an irreducible component $Z$ of $f^{-1}(y)$, so we have $0=\operatorname{codim}_{f^{-1}(y)}Z = \dim \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}$.

Answer (score 2):

use $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\otimes \kappa(y)=\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}y, \:x}$ . Then  $dim(f^{-1}y)=dim(\overline{\{x\}})=dim(Z)$ as all components of the fibre $f^{-1}y$ have the same dimension, hence (the prime corresponding to) $x$ has height $0$ in the ring $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}y}$. So localising at $x$ gives $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}y,x}$ a zero dimensional (=Artinian) ring.

**Edit** The fibres of f are equidimensional because $f$ is dominant and of finite type see also [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B2H).
Why? You may reduce to the case $f: \mathbf{Spec}(A) \rightarrow \mathbf{Spec}(B)$ is dominant where $B$ is a discrete valuation ring with residue field $\kappa$ and field of fraction $K$ and $A\subset B$ is a finite type algebra over $B$. Then $dim(A\otimes \kappa)=dim(A\otimes K)$, so the dimension of the special fibre is the dimension of the generic fibre and that IS equidimension by definition.

Comment: O.K. Thank you. Can I ask question? 1) Why $f^{-1}(y)$ is equidimensional(every irreducible components have same dimension) 2) Some confusion : You wrote "$x$ has height $0$ in the ring $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y)}$" . But $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y)}$ is a structure sheaf of the fiiber $f^{-1}(y)$, not look like a ring. What you mean exactly?

Comment: I edited the post concerning (1). Concerning (2): most certainly $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(x)}$ is a ring, because it is a locally ringed space, as it is a subscheme of $X$. Every scheme is a locally ringed space, i.e. on every open the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is a ring and the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{U,x}$ is a local ring.

Comment: if you're happy with the answer, accept it so it can be closed. If not, ask more.

Comment: 1) I looked the link you attached. In the link, what theorem or proof is assoiciated with the equidimensionality of fibers under the condition of dominance and of finite typeness?   2) I'm still confused about the sentence 'localising of $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y)}$ at $x$'. $(f^{-1}(y), \mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y)})$ is subscheme of $X$(?). $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y)}$ is structure sheaf on $f^{-1}(y)$, not seems to be ring itself. But  $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}$ is certainly local ring, called the local ring of $f^{-1}(y)$ at $x$.

Comment: It can't seem to see $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}$ as the localization of $\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y)}$ at $x$ :)

Comment: the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ is a sheaf of rings and you can always reduce to the case where $f|_{f^{-1}y}:f^{-1}y \rightarrow y$ is a morphism between affine schemes and the structure sheaf of an affine scheme IS a ring, see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02FW)

Comment: O.K. ~ I think that I understand that why we may assume that $f^{-1}(y) = \operatorname{spec}B$ is affine. (If nedeed, I have intention of sharing my argument~~)  And it seems that one of key point is that $\operatorname{dim}f^{-1}(y) = \operatorname{dim}Z$. And I still don't know why this is exactly true. And perhaps.. is there any other way to prove $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(y),x}=0$ by bypassing the equidimensionality of $f^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: In fact, this question originally related to my previews question :
    
     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544844/showing-that-operatornamedimf-1-eta-cap-x-operatornamedim-t  Perhaps, there, we have $\operatorname{dim}f^{-1}(\eta) = \operatorname{dim}(f^{-1}(\eta) \cap X')$?

Comment: Anyway Thanks for answer!~

Comment: Uhm..for me now it is difficult to follow your speed of argument :) In the Edit, 1) by field of fraction $K$, field of fraction of what? And 2) you wrote "that is equidimension by definition". My question is, definition of what? Perhaps, you used the Lemma 33.19.2. in the link (Stacks project)? 3) And why the equidimensionality of the special fiber implies that of $f^{-1}(y)$? Can we choose the $\operatorname{Spec}B$ such that it contains $y$ as special point?

Comment: I want to understand completely~~

Comment: (1) field of fraction of $A$. (2) That is the definition of equidimension, which you should maybe get familiar with first. (3) Yes this is true

Comment: For me, your argument is somewhat compressive. Can you explain each step more in detail? For example , 1) the reductibility to such $f : \operatorname{Spec}A \to \operatorname{Spec}B$, 2)  $dim(A \otimes \kappa) = dim(A \otimes K)$, 3) equality of the dimension of special fiber and that of generic fiber  4) Equidimensionality of the special fiber from this equality. etc..  Anyway I'll try to it.

Comment: Can I come back again after struggling with your stuff?

Comment: I think that I don't know some knowledge :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139696/discussion-between-sisi-and-plantation).