# For $y \in Y$, does there exists an open neighborhood $\operatorname{Spec}B$ where $B$ is DVR and containing the $y$ as the special point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be an irreducible locally noetherian, universally catenary scheme. Let $y\in Y$. Then
does there exists an open affine neighborhood $\operatorname{Spec}B$ such that

1. $B$ is a discrete valuation ring.
2. $\operatorname{Spec}B $ contains the $y$ as the speical point.

?

This question originates from trial to show that

> "Let $Y$ be an irreducible locally noetherian, universally catenary scheme. If $f:X→Y$ is dominant and locally of finte type, then each fiber of $f$ is equidimensional? "

(c.f. See : [Why $\operatorname{dim}\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} \kappa(y)=0$ in certain situation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546260/why-operatornamedim-mathcalo-x-x-otimes-mathcalo-y-y-kappay-0) , answer of Sisi (Edit). There, he uses https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00QK.
If needed, I will upload my own more detailed argument or progress that I made. )

Can anyone help?

Comment: If $y$ is a closed point then $B$ is in general not a discrete valuation ring, that happens only if $Y$ is one dimensional. However the local ring  of y $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ has $y$ as its special point but it’s in general not an open neighborhood.

Comment: @Sisi : Thanks for comment. So..our qeustion is false? In the linked question, below of your answer, I asked that "Can we choose the $\operatorname{Spec}B$ such that it contains $y$ as special point?"and you answered affirmatively..("Yes this is true") How do you think about this now?

Comment: I said you can choose the target to be affine $Spec(B)$ around $y$. $B$ is not a DVR in general and I never said that

Comment: In the link, you wrote, "You may reduce to the case $f:Spec(A)→Spec(B)$ is dominant where $B$ is a discrete valuation ring with residue field $\kappa$ and field of fraction $K$ and $B⊂A$ is a finite type algebra over $B$." How can we reduce to the case? If you have time, can you explain more in detail?

Comment: Do not change your question after it has been answered.  Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: @Xander Henderson : O.K.~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us follow the convention of the stacks project: that $\dim_y Y := \operatorname{min}(\dim U)$ where $U$ ranges over the open subsets of $Y$ containing $y$. If what you said was true, then $\dim_y Y \leq 1$ for all $y \in Y$. Therefore, $$\dim Y = \sup_{y \in Y} \dim_y Y \leq 1$$ where the equality is [lemma 28.10.2 in the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04MU). As such, this couldn't work for schemes $Y$ of dimension $\geq 2$.

Comment: +1, good explanation. There are also other obstructions: as an open subscheme of a Jacobson scheme is again Jacobson and therefore has the closed points dense, any such $Y$ cannot be Jacobson. So for instance $Y$ cannot be a variety over a field.